# Rendering React via Jade (Pug)

Tags: express, reactjs, pug

So I'm using Jade (Pug) to render my templates via Node, and I'm trying to use React to interact with various HTML elements. Is there a special way to do this?

**React (favourite-item.js)**

```
var FavouriteItemButton = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {favourite: false};
    },
    handleClick: function (event) {
        this.setState({favourite: !this.state.favourite});
    },
    render: function() {
        var text = this.state.favourite ? 'like' : 'haven\t liked';
        return (
            <p onClick={this.handleClick}>
                You {text} this. Click to toggle.
            </p>
        );
    }
});

RenderDOM.render(
    <FavouriteItemButton />,
    document.getElementById('example')
);
```

I've imported React/React DOM and obviously the file above. I have a HTML element on my Jade (index.jade) template:

```
p#example like
```

But nothing is changing on click, I presume it's down to the tags or some special way to render React elements via Jade.

My includes:

```
script(type='text/javascript' src='js/libs/react.min.js')
script(type='text/javascript' src='js/libs/react-dom.js')
script(type='text/babel' src='js/favourite-item.js')
```

I'm right in thinking I should include the type as text/babel?

Comment: Doesn't sound like this has anything to do with jade.. do you see the text `You haven't liked this. Click to toggle.` on the page?

Comment: @azium I do not. I added a p#example like - thinking it would override that?

Comment: It's the opposite in fact... React appends itself to the element you specify in render blowing out its contents and replacing it with the React application. You almost never interact with existing dom elements, jade/html/whatever, when working with React. Also you have `RenderDOM.render` that should certainly be `ReactDOM.render`. I imagine you're getting errors in the console.

Comment: Strangely enough there were no errors in the console... I have changed that now though (didn't fix the issue though, strange.)

Comment: Are you sure your javascript is even running on the page? If you put a `console.log` somewhere does it log?

Comment: I tried doing a 'console.log' in favourite-item.js and nothing showed up, yet it's included using: 'script(type='text/babel' src='js/favourite-item.js')'

Comment: You need to include babel for that work <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>

Comment: It's now working! My bad. Thanks for the debugging help :)